# Underfull \vbox detected (badness 10000) detected at line 1

Tags: warnings

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{cite}                       % For quotations

\newcommand{\virg}[1]{``#1''}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{enumitem}                    % FOR LISTS
\usepackage{microtype}                   % Migliora riempimento righe
\usepackage{indentfirst, noindentafter}
\usepackage{titling} % Customizing the title section

% FORMAT

%\setlength{\textwidth}{14 cm} \setlength{\textheight}{22. cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0. cm} \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{30pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{20pt} \linespread{1.4}

%\pagestyle{myheadings}

\pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove headline
\fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
\fancyfoot{} % Blank out the default footer
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{\thepage} % Custom footer text

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

% FOR LISTS

\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt}

% TITLE

\setlength{\droptitle}{-4\baselineskip} % Move the title up
\title{Thich Nhat Hanh - La pace è ogni respiro}
\author{Francesco Gemma}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{Motivazioni}

Negli ultimi mesi ho capito di essere costantemente sopraffatto dai miei pensieri, dalle mie abitudine, dai miei automatismi. Non che prima non lo sapessi; solo che adesso l'ho \emph{realizzato}, fatto \emph{reale}, e ho deciso di cambiare quanto più possibile di me stesso. 

Capita a tutti di non vivere appieno un momento della giornata, di svolgere una qualsiasi attività ma di pensare ad altro. Può essere un impegno, una scadenza, una preoccupazione, un litigio... Si cerca di svagarsi ascoltando musica, passeggiando, allenandosi, facendo le pulizie, guardando un film. Ma difficilmente ci distacchiamo dai quei pensieri. È come se si fosse scissi in due, l'Io e la Mente, e che questa abbia il controllo sul primo. Trovare l'equilibrio tra le due sfere sembra quasi impossibile.

Queste speculazioni sono più concrete di quanto non possa sembrare. Chi, come me, non riesce a concentrarsi e perfino a dormire bene, perché non riesce a gestire ansie, emozioni, pensieri, si ritroverà in quanto dico. Dedicare il giusto tempo alla nostra Mente è allora fondamentale, per vivere dando un'adeguata importanza ai nostri affanni.

\emph{Affanno} sembra la parola più adatta. La sensazione che ho quando dormo è di essere prigioniero di me stesso. Anche, non respiro correttamente e i sogni ne sono il riflesso:
\begin{itemize}
\item sono inseguito e non riesco a scappare,
\item gioco a calcio ma non riesco a muovermi e cado a terra dolorante perché le gambe non mi sostengono,
\item qualcuno mi vuole strozzare
\end{itemize}
e così via. Devo ammettere che rido sempre nel raccontarla, ma \emph{vivere} quest'esperienza è comunque disturbante. Quando chiesi aiuto ad uno psicologo mi diede i seguenti consigli:
\begin{enumerate}
\item bloccare i pensieri, farsene un'immagine nitida nella mente, rinviarli allo scoccare dell'ora. Poi dedicarvisi per cinque minuti esatti. Ogni ora, ogni giorno. Quando pronti, rinviare ogni due ore, poi tre e così via...
\item usare il letto solo per dormire.
\item se ci si sveglia durante la notte, alzarsi e fare qualcosa di noioso fino a quando non si riprende sonno. Se entro venti minuti non ci si riaddormenta, rialzarsi e annoiarsi nuovamente.
\end{enumerate}
Sono sicuro che questi consigli vi saranno utili (specialmente il primo, al di là che dormiate bene o meno).

\section*{La via del respiro}

Se l'affanno è il demone insito in noi, il respiro è l'arma per sconfiggerlo. Ciò comporta una grande difficoltà: concentrarsi. Provate a sedervi o sdraiarvi comodamente e curare solo il vostro respiro. Dopo pochi secondi comincerete a pensare a tutt'altro. I mostri del passato e le preoccupazioni per il futuro ci distraggono dall'unica dimensione temporale che viviamo: il \emph{presente}.

Recentemente, nello stato di confusione che ho attraversato ho visto molti video motivazionali e di autodisciplina. Il consiglio universale è quello di dare valore al proprio tempo. Che è forse il consiglio più banale ma allo stesso tempo più difficile da seguire. Ma una volta \emph{realizzato} quanti pensieri, energia e ore spendiamo inutilmente, una piccola verità ci si manifesterà: abbiamo la possibilità di dedicarci a noi stessi ogni giorno, per migliorarci e migliorare gli altri, e la perdiamo puntualmente. La via per liberarsi dalle distrazioni io non posso indicarvela, perché non è unica per tutti e dipende da cosa intendiamo per \virg{distrazione} (si suppone, comunque, che sia direttamente o indirettamente dannosa). Posso però riportavi quanto letto nel piccolo ma illuminante \emph{La pace è ogni respiro}, del monaco buddista Thich Nhat Hanh. Se non avete al momento la pazienza di meditare quotidianamente (per dieci minuti stando fermi a respirare), i seguenti sono consigli per concentravi sul \emph{qui ed ora}:
\begin{enumerate}
\item A colazione, pranzo e cena, dedicatevi solo al cibo, a come cucinarlo e ad assaporarlo. Potete focalizzare l'attenzione sui colori e il profumo. Riconoscere quanto si è fortunati ad avere quel piatto davanti, al di là della fede in un dio. Evitare l'utilizzo del cellulare e della televisione (per un'ora non sarà impossibile). Si può parlare con i parenti o i coinquilini o, perché no, osservare il silenzio.
\item Quando ci si lava, sentire l'effetto dell'acqua sulla pelle. Le docce lunghe di fine giornata in cui ci perdiamo nei pensieri del giorno sono controproducenti, sia per lo spreco d'acqua, sia perché i pensieri rimangono nella nostra testa. Rivolgiamo la nostra attenzione solo all'acqua. Analogo discorso per quando laviamo i denti. Dedichiamoci solo ad essi. Così per lo shampoo, l'asciugatura e la pettinatura dei capelli, la pulizia delle orecchie, la cura delle mani e dei piedi. Siamo fortunati a poter purificare il nostro corpo e con esso la mente. È meraviglioso che basta aprire un rubinetto per aver ad disposizione l'acqua. Non sempre è stato così e non dobbiamo ricordarlo solo quando essa manca.
\item Quando passeggiamo o ci rechiamo in qualche luogo, concentriamoci sui nostri passi. Uno dopo l'altro, raggiungiamo la nostra meta. Siamo fortunati a poter camminare.
\end{enumerate} 

Tutto ciò risulterà difficile e a tratti bizzarro. Non vi prometto che avrete il sorriso stampato sulle labbra, come in una qualunque pubblicità. Lo scopo, comunque, è quello di prendere consapevolezza di ciò che si sta facendo. Non saremo con la mente da un'altra parte, ma saremo un tutt'uno con il corpo. Eviteremo il sovraccarico di pensieri che si accumulano durante il giorno e disporremo di diverse pause tra i vari impegni, che richiedono le nostre energie. La cosa non è affatto banale: l'utilizzo continuo del cellulare, ad esempio, distrae e stressa il nostro cervello e disturba la sua regolare attività.

\section*{Sono un'isola in me stesso}

Secondo gli insegnamenti del Buddha, c'è un luogo perfettamente sicuro in cui possiamo tornare, ovunque siamo e in ogni momento. Quel luogo è l'isola del nostro vero io. Qui le tempeste della vita non possono turbarci. Quando si assume consapevolezza di sé e pratichiamo un'adeguata respirazione, i cinque \emph{skandhas} del buddismo (gli \emph{aggregati} o \emph{elementi} che costituiscono una persona) si riuniscono. Tali skandhas sono il corpo, le sensazioni, le percezioni, le formazioni mentali e la coscienza.
Lasciatevi ispirare dalla seguente poesia:
\begin{verse}
Sono un'isola in me stesso,\\
il Buddha è la mia consapevolezza, brilla vicino e lontano.\\
Il Dharma è il mio respiro, veglia su corpo e mente.\\
Sono libero.\\
Come un'isola in me stesso,\\
il Sangha è i miei cinque skandhas che lavora in armonia.\\
Rifugiandomi in me, tornando a me stesso,\\
sono libero.\\
Inspirando, espirando,\\
sboccio come un fiore,\\
sono fresco come rugiada.\\
Sono solido come una montagna,\\
sono stabile come la terra.\\
Sono libero.\\
Inspirando, espirando,\\
sono l'acqua che riflette ciò che è vero, cioè che è reale;\\
e sento che c'è spazio nel mio profondo.\\
Sono libero.
\end{verse}

Il Buddha è il maestro al quale vi ispirate. Può essere Gesù, Maometto o chiunque voi considerate come la luce che vi guida. Il Dharma sono gli insegnamenti e il percorso verso la comprensione e l'amore. Il Sangha è la comunità spirituale di amici che ci supporta nel nostro cammino.

L'interpretazione dei versi è soggettiva, ma vi presento quella del monaco.

\subsection*{Sboccio come un fiore, sono fresco come rugiada}

Per essere felici e rendere felici gli altri, abbiamo bisogno di una certa freschezza. Guardando a un bambino che gioca o dorme, vedremo in lui una spontaneità ed un'energia che a noi sembrano perdute. Egli è splendido come un fiore appena sbocciato. Anche noi siamo dei fiori; ma per le difficoltà della vita perdiamo la nostra freschezza, rischiando di appassire e abbandonarsi al suolo. Scrive il saggio vietnamita Nguyen Binh
\begin{verse}
Basta pianti, basta lamenti,\\
questa è l'ultima poesia di malcontento.\\
Quando smettiamo di lamentarci, la nostra anima di rinfresca.\\
Quando cessiamo di piangere, gli occhi tornano limpidi.
\end{verse}
Inspirate, rilassate il corpo e sorridetevi.

\subsection*{Sono solido come una montagna, sono stabile come la terra}

Non si può ottenere la pace senza la stabilità. Quando corpo e mente sono instabili, diventiamo nervosi e agitati. Sicché neanche gli altri possono fidarsi di noi. Mantenendo la concentrazione sul respiro, avrete una solida base per riconoscere ciò che accade dentro di voi, per accettarlo ed accoglierlo. Con intelligenza e compassione, supererete le difficoltà quotidiane. Ciò aumenterà la vostra autostima, rendendovi ancora più solidi.

\subsection*{Sono l'acqua che riflette ciò che è vero, ciò che è reale}

L'immagine di uno specchio d'acqua evoca tranquillità a capacità di interpretare la realtà senza distorsioni. Quando formazioni mentali come la rabbia, la gelosia, l'invidia, la paura turbano la nostra mente, rischiamo di trarre conclusioni sbagliate dalle osservazioni. Con le persone non ci sentiamo in sintonia e non riusciamo a comunicare. Una mente calma, invece, saprà riflettere limpidamente la realtà. Respirando, proiettiamo le formazioni mentali e riconosciamole.

\subsection*{Sento che c'è spazio nel mio profondo}

I pensieri sono come foglie. Si accumulano uno sopra l'altro e, a un certo punto, è necessario rimuoverli. Esercitatevi a lasciar andare le cose insignificanti che non vi portano alcuna felicità. Quando imparerete a lasciar andare, avrete più spazio.

Immaginate, ma non occorre tanto sforzo, una persona che va al mercato e appena vede un oggetto a basso costo lo compra, sebbene non gli sia particolarmente necessario. A poco a poco riempirà gli armadi, le mensole, i mobili, la casa di cianfrusaglie. Fino a quando gli rimarrà poco spazio per vivere. Similmente, se abbiamo troppe preoccupazioni, dubbi e paure, non ci rimane più spazio per vivere e amare.

Il buddhismo insegna che la gioia e la felicità derivano dal lasciar andare. Fate un inventario della vostra vita. Ci sono cose a cui siete attaccati che neanche utilizzate e vi privano della vostra libertà. Trovate il coraggio di donarle a qualcuno o di disfarvene. Il vento e le onde rovesciano facilmente una barca sovraccarica. Alleggeritela e viaggerà più libera e sicura. Potete offrire il dono prezioso della libertà e dello spazio ai vostri cari, ma solo se è già presente nel vostro cuore.

\section*{Conclusioni}

La consapevolezza è il bene più prezioso che possiamo avere. Essere consapevoli è necessario per liberarsi dalle ansie e dal superfluo, per trovare l'equilibrio e la felicità nostra e degli altri. Ci aiuterà a gestire le nostre emozioni e i rapporti interpersonali, i nostri desideri non prevarranno e non acquisteremo oggetti inutili, vivremo nel rispetto della nostra e altrui persona. 
\end{document}
```

I'm writing this article and I get the warning

```
Underfull \vbox detected (badness 10000) detected at line 1
```

but I really don't grasp the problem. For example, if I wipe out after the first `itemize`, the warning is solved.

Also, do you have any general tips about margins and linespread? I feel they're always a mess.

Finally, what's the best way to write a quotation under the date?

Thanks.

Comment: line 1 would be surprising, I get `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [3]`

Comment: Don't play with `\topmargin`, `\oddsidemargin` and similar: load `geometry` and use it's more powerful methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is actually

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [3]
```

showing the problem is on page 3

as you have `twoside` option, `\flushbottom` is in effect but you have removed all the stretchy space around the list and there is no other stretch on the page so tex can not make the last line reach the bottom of the page.

restoring some variable space makes the setting feasible again:

```
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep, topsep=0pt plus 2pt}
                                         %%%%%%%%%
```

This says the space above and below the list defaults to 0pt but may stretch to 2pt

Comment: Great! Is there any reference I can study for such warnings?

Comment: the TeXBook is the official documentation @FrancescoGemma